# best aproach to distinct query result before importing it into Excel cells

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, excel, vba

I have a query which grabs data from Access with contents:

> A,1,z
>
> A,2,z
>
> B,1,y
>
> A,1,i

I created 3 dropdowns in excel and I want to populate them with rows from these columns. The problem is that in each column there are duplicates and I want to get rid of them. I am looking for a solution to get rid of these duplicates.

Current process is following:

1. run a query. I use VBA in Excel. Access is being queried.
2. paste results into a separate sheet **(it takes A LOT of time because there are 20k reocrds)**
3. assign a range for my dropdows

As you can see my second step is very resource hog and the proccess time should drop drastically by removing duplicates from each column.

**What is the best approach to populate dropdowns with unique values from query?**

My ideas

- create a query which will output me:

> A,1,z
>
> B,2,y
>
> , ,i

In that case i will not have to distinct values manually in excel. Not possible to do, as I understand...

- Add values from each columns to List, remove doubles, paste result into excel. This is my personal favorite because I see no other ways to fix the issue.
- create multiple queries to DISTINCT each table_column separately.. Not very fast solution, I suppose
- some other approach

Answer (score 1):

Run three `SELECT DISTINCT Colx FROM table` queries to get the values for the three dropdowns. Your option two. The work has to be done sometime so you might as well use the tools designed to do the work instead of reinventing that wheel.

Comment: except i have 10 columns to select. And it takes 3 seconds to run a query for each one of them ;) Otherwise, yes, I would have used it..

Answer (score 0):

If you use `select distinct columna, columnb...` instead of `select columna, columnb...` you will get what you want. The SQL will take longer to run, though.

Comment: it doesn't work like this.. I am still getting duplicates. in one of my columns there is only 1 unique value, in my other column 10 are unique and in third there are 100 unique values. SQL wont return me a result, when columns have different row amounts

Comment: You could combine this approach with the one I suggested - build a query for the distinct combinations, then query each column of the distinct combinations. My guess is access will handle this just fine, if not Simon's distinct combinations query could create a temp table that you could query directly. Also, you may be able to get away with just running these queries periodically instead of on demand.